# Perform multiple conditions on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have found myself looping through a Dataframe column to perform conditions, and based off those conditions the following result is adjacent to that cell. Is there a more efficient way to perform this?

For example I have the dataframe df:

```
  A          B
potato
orange
watermelon
lettuce


... etc.
```

I would perform the following code:

```
for i in range(len(df['A']):
    if df['A'].iloc[i] == 'watermelon':
        df['B'].iloc[i] = 'red'
    elif df['A'].iloc[i] == 'lettuce':
        df['B'].iloc[i] = 'green'
    elif .... :
```

result:

```
  A          B
potato     brown
orange     orange 
watermelon red
lettuce    green
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop or `apply()`, use [**`Series.replace()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a `fruit:color` dictionary:

```py
fruit_color = dict(potato='brown', watermelon='red', lettuce='green')
df['B'] = df['A'].replace(fruit_color)

#             A       B
# 0      potato   brown
# 1      orange  orange
# 2  watermelon     red
# 3     lettuce   green
```